# PyCryptoDome dependency error despite it already being downloaded

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pypdf

I am experimenting with PyPDF2 and using it in order to read PDF Files in a google drive, using Google Colab of course. I'm however getting a strange error in the following code:

```
!pip install pycryptodomex
!pip install pycryptodome
pdf_files = [file for file in os.listdir(dir) if file.endswith('.pdf')]
raw_text = ""
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    pdf_path = os.path.join(dir, pdf_file)
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PdfReader(file)
        for i, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
            text = page.extract_text()
            if text:
                raw_text += text

print(raw_text[:100])
```

```
DependencyError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-0f2bd9784178> in <cell line: 4>()
      6     with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
      7         reader = PdfReader(file)
----> 8         for i, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
      9             text = page.extract_text()
     10             if text:

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PyPDF2/_encryption.py in decrypt(self, data)
    145 
    146         def decrypt(self, data: bytes) -> bytes:
--> 147             raise DependencyError("PyCryptodome is required for AES algorithm")
    148 
    149     def RC4_encrypt(key: bytes, data: bytes) -> bytes:

DependencyError: PyCryptodome is required for AES algorithm
```

As you can see from my original code, I have already successfully installed PyCryptoDome and even PyCryptoDomex (as reflected from the Google Colab Terminal), yet this dependency error keeps on popping up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have it installed - or at least not in the right environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely an encrypted .pdf file. I had the same issue and resolved it by skipping said file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).